# R: Filtering by two columns using "is not equal" operator dplyr/subset

Tags: r, dplyr

This questions must have been answered before but I cannot find it any where. I need to filter/subset a dataframe using values in two columns to remove them. In the examples I want to keep all the rows that are not equal (!=) to both replicate "1" and treatment "a". However, either subset and filter functions remove all replicate 1 and all treatment a. I could solve it by using which and then indexing, but it is not the best way for using pipe operator. do you know why filter/subset do not filter only when both conditions are true?

```
require(dplyr)

#Create example dataframe
replicate = rep(c(1:3), times = 4)
treatment = rep(c("a","b"), each = 6)

df = data.frame(replicate, treatment)

#filtering data    
> filter(df, replicate!=1, treatment!="a")
  replicate treatment
1         2         b
2         3         b
3         2         b
4         3         b
> subset(df, (replicate!=1 & treatment!="a"))
   replicate treatment
8          2         b
9          3         b
11         2         b
12         3         b

#solution by which - indexing
index = which(df$replicate==1 & df$treatment=="a")
> df[-index,]
   replicate treatment
2          2         a
3          3         a
5          2         a
6          3         a
7          1         b
8          2         b
9          3         b
10         1         b
11         2         b
12         3         b
```

Comment: User or `|` instead of `&`. The filter conditions are by default combined with `&`. `filter(df, replicate!=1 | treatment!="a")`

Comment: It worked like a charm. I was confused because I understood `&` operator to give TRUE only when both conditions are TRUE and `|` operator to give TRUE with only one condition to be TRUE or both, which is true for `which` function. So odd that is like that in `subset` and `filter`. Anyways, thank you very much my friend! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're looking to use an "or" condition here. How does this look:

```
require(dplyr)

#Create example dataframe
replicate = rep(c(1:3), times = 4)
treatment = rep(c("a","b"), each = 6)

df = data.frame(replicate, treatment)
df %>% 
  filter(replicate != 1 | treatment != "a")

   replicate treatment
1          2         a
2          3         a
3          2         a
4          3         a
5          1         b
6          2         b
7          3         b
8          1         b
9          2         b
10         3         b
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. I was confused because I understood `&` operator to give TRUE only when both conditions are TRUE and `|` operator to give TRUE with only one condition to be TRUE or both, which is true for `which` function. So odd that is like that in `subset` and `filter`. Anyways, thank you very much my friend! :)

Comment: No problem! You are correct in most cases, but when you're specifying "not" e.g., "!=", then you would want to use "or" instead of "and."

Comment: Also, if you feel your question has been answered, go ahead and hit the check mark to close it.